# How can I clear screen command history?

Tags: bash, history, gnu-screen

I'm using screen command after ssh to a public remote machine with Ubuntu 14.04 so that I could continue my sessions whenever I want. I've found that some admins are tracking my command history and they have access to my screen sessions too.
I know that I can clear my bash history commands by removing .bash_history file in my home directory but couldn't find a way to clear my screen sessions' command history too.

Comment: What do you mean by screen command history? Usually screen starts a shell and you run commands in that shell, so you need to clear that shell's history.

Comment: Exactly, I want to delete that shell's history. But I can't find a way for it.

Comment: Try `echo $0` or `ls -l /proc/$$/exe` to see what shell you're running then.

Comment: So that shell is also bash, and you already know how to delete bash history. What's the problem?

Comment: I want the history to be gone for the current session not after I start a fresh one. I don't want to lose my current screen session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command you are looking for is `history`

To delete your current session it would be

```
history -c
```

To delete your current session and previous ones you would use both commands

```
history -c && history -w
```